# showing current data in android UI without refreshing and delaying

Tags: android

I want to fetch temperature data from a database which keep changing and display in android UI without delaying and refreshing the screen. Like a live data.

I tried using asynchronous but there is a delay of second and I tried with swiping re

Comment: Welcome, and please consider reading this to get better results here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you're new to this. learn more about callbacks. what you should do is to update the database on one thread (background thread) and update the UI on UI-Thread. you can use RxJava to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following, make the View and the collection it's receiving (as argument) accessible to the method that's updating the database. Then every time the database gets updated, update the collection and the View, that should do it.

Comment: Any example link is available for better understanding. Thanks